# How to turn a private plunk to public without forking?

Tags: plunker

I have a private plunk and I'd like to turn it public but I don't want fork it, so having two plunks.

Any way just to change the visibility to public?

Answer (score -2):

Click Fork and select "Fork to public Fork"

[image]

Comment: Without forking please.

Comment: It did not support that
Please uncheck "private plunk" before save